# Are eddy currents produced by a coil of copper wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, lenz-law

if I were too drop a magnet down a length of coiled copper wire would the motion of the magnet be opposed by eddy currents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnet's motion would be opposed by electrical currents induced in the wire. I wouldn't call these "eddy currents" since they flow in the same direction along the entire wire, but that's just a point about names. You can connect a light bulb to the coil and it will light up as the magnet passes through.

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sENgdSF8ppA) of a magnet moving past various arrangements of copper. The coil demonstration starts at 1:49.

Comment: Thank you very much, when I was originally doing this lab it didn't occur to me that of course you would need a complete circuit for the electrons to be displaced and thus for resistance to occur. Also that video was hugely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> if I were too drop a magnet down a length of coiled copper wire would the motion of the magnet be opposed by eddy currents?

Yes, but the eddy currents would be much smaller than if you had either a solid copper tube, or a series of rings.

The fact that an insulator (the air or wire insulation) is present where the current would "prefer" to flow will break up the eddy currents in a manner very similar to what happens in the laminated core of a laminated core transformer. Eddy currents exist, but at reduced amplitude.

You could increase the eddy currents by connecting the two ends of the coil together.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, how could eddy currents form in disconnected copper wire if the electrons can't be displaced?

Comment: @naman1008 Who says the electrons cannot be displaced? Any lump of metal, no matter the shape, can have eddy currents. Some shapes are more conducive to the formation of eddy currents than others, but electrons can always be displaced in metals.

Comment: Ya that makes sense, so then having a connected circuit is just more conducive to electron displacement and thus produces more resistance?

Comment: @naman1008 "so then having a connected circuit is just more conducive to electron displacement" yes. "and thus produces more resistance?" I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why it is that a disconnected coil of copper wire produces less resistance on a magnet moving through it than a connected coil of copper wire.

Comment: The emf (electromotive force) around an eddy current loop depends upon the amount changing magnetic flux enclosed by the loop. The current density in such a loop is the emf around the loop divided by the resistivity of the material. Certain shapes permit loops that enclose a large area, and hence large emf. Other shapes only permit smaller loops.